# C++ code to automatically close console

Tags: c++, console

I am currently learning C++ for a programming course. I noticed that my professor's program automatically closes at the end of their program. It usually prompts the user for an input, and then upon entering an input, the program closes. How would I code that? I only know using return 0 gets me "Press Any Key to Continue"

Note: this is a `.exe` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your program doesn't wait for any input, it runs and finally exits from the program. On exiting, the console automatically closes. I assume, to run the program you're clicking on the .exe, as opposed to runnng the program from `cmd.exe`, or you run the program from visual studio itself without debugging.

Comment: Judging from the "press any key" message Andy mentioned, I'm guessing he is running it without debugging from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You could just put the following line before `return 0;`:

```
std::cin.get();
```

It will wait for some input and then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

use `getch();` before `return;` statement

Answer (score 1):

Return 0 to give "press any jey to continue" is debugger-specific behavior. Running your compiled exe outside the debugger usually wont show that.

The simple code below does a little more than you're asking for (it repeats what you typed in) but still gives the general idea.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "enter something" << endl;
    string stuff;
    cin >> stuff;
    cout << "You entered " << stuff << " you insensitive clod" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy, at the end of your main() function put this:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

this define a new variable and tries to fill it with user-input and then the program will not be terminated till the user gives it input. This is how the program reaches the `Press any key to continue`, finally you exit the program with a `0` argument and the console window will be destroyed automatically since it is the main window of the process.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.sync();
std::cin.get();
```

cause there may be times when you need to write something and you will need to press ENTER which will make

```
std::cin.get();
```

useles. As it will remeber the first time you pressed ENTER and close the window.

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Your name: ";
    std::cin >> name;           \\ <--Place where you press ENTER <--------------
    std::cout << "Hi, " << name << ".";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```